# Funcion no definida en python

Tags: python, funciones

Tengo un error en el siguiente codigo en python que me indica que una de las funciones no esta definida. Estoy fijandome en las tabulaciones del codigo y las veo correctas, inicio con la clase, luego las funciones y finalmente con la ejecucion del codigo. Esta ultima al mismo nivel de tabulacion que la clase inicial pero no encuentro el error, les dejo el codigo:

```
class Libro():
    _Tamaño="17x24"
    Paginas=0
    PrecioVta=0
    Peso=0
    _PrecioxPag=0
    _PesoxPag=0
    Titulo=""
    Tapa=""
    URL=""
    ISBN=""
    Estado="No Registrado"
    
    def _init_(self,):
        self._Tamaño="17x24"
        self._PrecioxPag=300
        self._PesoxPag=0.8
    def RegistrarLibro(self):
        Estado="Registrado"
        return Estado
    def PrecioxPagina(self):
        return self._PrecioxPag
    def PesoxPagina(self):
        return self._PesoxPag
    def TamañoLibro(self):
        return self._Tamaño
    def DatosLibro(Libro,NumPags,Nombre,TipoTapa,URLLibro,ISBNLibro):
        Libro.Paginas=NumPags
        Libro.PrecioVta=Libro.PrecioxPagina()*NumPags
        Libro.Peso=Libro.PesoxPagina()*NumPags
        Libro.Titulo=Nombre
        Libro.Tapa=TipoTapa
        Libro.URL=URLLibro
        Libro.ISBN=ISBNLibro
    def RecibeDatosLibro(Libro):
        Nombre=input("Titulo Libro: ")
        NumPags=int(input("Num pags: "))
        TipoTapa=input("TapaDura (D), TapaBlanda (B): ")
        URLLibro=input("URL? (S/N): ")
        ISBNLibro=input("ISBN: ")
        print("***************************************************************")
        DatosLibro(Libro,NumPags,Nombre,TipoTapa,URLLibro,ISBNLibro)
            
    def MuestraDatosLibro(Libro):
        print("Tamaño= ",Libro.TamañoLibro())
        print("Paginas= ",Libro.Paginas)
        print("Precio Venta= ",Libro.PrecioVta, "COP")
        print("Peso= ",round(Libro.Peso,2), "gms")
        print("PrecioxPag= ",round(Libro.PrecioxPagina(),2))
        print("PesoxPag= ",Libro.PesoxPagina())
        print("Titulo= ",Libro.Titulo)
        print("Tapa= ",Libro.Tapa)
        print("URL= ",Libro.URL)
        print("ISBN= ",Libro.ISBN)
        print("Estado= ",Libro.Estado)
        print("****************************************************************")
    
Libro1=Libro()
Libro2=Libro()

print("DATOS LIBRO 1")
RecibeDatosLibro(Libro1)
print("DATOS LIBRO 2")
RecibeDatosLibro(Libro2)
#Mostrar los datos del primer libro
MuestraDatosLibro(Libro1)
#Mostrar los datos del segundo Libro
MuestraDatosLibro(Libro2)
```

El error es line 62, in 
RecibeDatosLibro(Libro1)
NameError: name 'RecibeDatosLibro' is not defined

Comment: La clase está mal definida. Los atributos como `ISBN` son atributos de instancia (uno distinto por cada objeto), no de clase (uno para todas las instancias). Además tienes un `__init__` sin parámetros para inicializar el objeto y en `DatosLibro` asignas los datos a la clase, no al objeto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RecibeDatosLibro aparece no definida porque la llamas como si fuese función independiente y resulta que está dentro de la clase libro; así que si la quieres llamar debes colocar `Libro.RecibeDatosLibro(Libro1)`. Pero yo te recomiendo sacar de la clase las funciones que pueden estar fuera de la clase. El código quedaría así.

```
class Libro():
    _Tamano="17x24"
    Paginas=0
    PrecioVta=0
    Peso=0
    _PrecioxPag=0
    _PesoxPag=0
    Titulo=""
    Tapa=""
    URL=""
    ISBN=""
    Estado="No Registrado"
    
    def _init_(self):
        self._Tamano="17x24"
        self._PrecioxPag=300
        self._PesoxPag=0.8
    def RegistrarLibro(self):
        Estado="Registrado"
        return Estado
    def PrecioxPagina(self):
        return self._PrecioxPag
    def PesoxPagina(self):
        return self._PesoxPag
    def TamanoLibro(self):
        return self._Tamano
def DatosLibro(Libro,NumPags,Nombre,TipoTapa,URLLibro,ISBNLibro):
    Libro.Paginas=NumPags
    Libro.PrecioVta=Libro.PrecioxPagina()*NumPags
    Libro.Peso=Libro.PesoxPagina()*NumPags
    Libro.Titulo=Nombre
    Libro.Tapa=TipoTapa
    Libro.URL=URLLibro
    Libro.ISBN=ISBNLibro
def RecibeDatosLibro(Libro):
    Nombre=input("Titulo Libro: ")
    NumPags=int(input("Num pags: "))
    TipoTapa=input("TapaDura (D), TapaBlanda (B): ")
    URLLibro=input("URL? (S/N): ")
    ISBNLibro=input("ISBN: ")
    print("***************************************************************")
    DatosLibro(Libro,NumPags,Nombre,TipoTapa,URLLibro,ISBNLibro)
        
def MuestraDatosLibro(Libro):
    print("Tamaño= ",Libro.TamanoLibro())
    print("Paginas= ",Libro.Paginas)
    print("Precio Venta= ",Libro.PrecioVta, "COP")
    print("Peso= ",round(Libro.Peso,2), "gms")
    print("PrecioxPag= ",round(Libro.PrecioxPagina(),2))
    print("PesoxPag= ",Libro.PesoxPagina())
    print("Titulo= ",Libro.Titulo)
    print("Tapa= ",Libro.Tapa)
    print("URL= ",Libro.URL)
    print("ISBN= ",Libro.ISBN)
    print("Estado= ",Libro.Estado)
    print("****************************************************************")

Libro1=Libro()

Libro2=Libro()
print("DATOS LIBRO 1")
RecibeDatosLibro(Libro1)
print("DATOS LIBRO 2")
RecibeDatosLibro(Libro2)
#Mostrar los datos del primer libro
MuestraDatosLibro(Libro1)
#Mostrar los datos del segundo Libro
MuestraDatosLibro(Libro2)
```

De esta manera, las puedes usar estas funciones de manera independiente.

Comment: Efectivamente el tema venia por que las funciones estaban todas agrupadas luego de la clase libro cuando eran independientes. Te agradezco tu ayuda